# Pulling last observation by Variable

Tags: sql, sas

How can i pull the last observation by a variable without sorting in SAS? Do anyone know how i can accomplish this using SQL query. The method i understand is using the last.variable in SAS but the table must not be sorted to get desired result. Thanks.

Comment: SQL would very likely perform a sort on the back end without telling you about it (unless you ask for the plan).  Are you trying to avoid this for the purpose of performance, or you don't want to sort because it's sorted by something already and you want the 'last.variable' by that sorting method?  Post some example data 'have' and 'want' if you want useful help.

Answer (score 1):

> Updated to better answer the question after clarification

If you have a transactional dataset without dates, but need to get the most recent transaction per ID, you could create a counter that will allow you to find the most recent transaction.

```
ID
2 
1 
4 
1 
2  
2
4
```

**Step 1: Create a counter for each transaction using a [sum statement](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000289454.htm)**

```
data have2(compress=yes); /* Dataset is compressed due to size */
    set have;
    transaction_nbr+1;
run;
```

This will yield:

```
ID transaction_nbr
2  1
1  2
4  3
1  4
2  5
2  6
4  7
```

**Step 2: Select the maximum transaction number from your new dataset**

```
proc sql noprint;
     create table want as
         select ID, transaction_nbr
         from have2
         where transaction_nbr in(select max(transaction_nbr) from have2 group by ID)
         order by ID;
quit;
```

Your dataset should now contain the most recent transaction per ID:

```
ID transaction_nbr
1  4
2  6
4  7
```

Here, you are getting everything all in one step. Because you created your own counter, the subquery in the `where` statement will guarantee that the transactions being selected are the most recent one.

Comment: Hello Stu, This didn't work. let me explain again. This table is a transactional table with no time stamp. So if i am trying to pull the last transaction i dont have a date parameter to use. So i need to pull the last transaction for that variable. After i pull the data, there is a place where i check a few of the id numbers to check if its correct.

Comment: However, when i run this code it works:                                              data temp  ;
set life  end=last;
where master_id = "xxxxxxxx";
if last;
run;                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Because it's a large dataset, i cannot use the where statement for all the ID's i need. I have tried the last.variable (sorted and notsorted) but didnt work

Comment: How large is the dataset? If you can merge both datasets together, then you can do so in one step. You might want to try using PROC SQL. I will update the code above to include this.

Comment: The dataset is very large but i can merge it together. That's not a problem

Comment: Stu, there is no date column in any of the table. The only way of picking the recent transaction is by picking the last in the list by ID.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. If that's the case, another way you can do it is by creating some sort of surrogate value where you can then do the above trick. I'll update again. Let me know if this is feasible.

Comment: You are quite welcome :) I am glad it worked! Sorry about misreading the question, I hadn't finished my morning coffee. That's about the only excuse I got :P

Comment: That's totally fine. Thanks again for your help. I appreciate it!